# Display data from database into a table using ajax, php and html

Tags: php, ajax, html

I'm trying to display data from database to a table using ajax, php and html without pressing any buttons or refreshing. Here is shipping.php where is the php code:

```
<?php
      require_once '../core/init.php';
      if(!is_logged_in()){
        header('Location: login.php');
      }
      include 'includes/head.php';
      include 'includes/navigation.php';
      $txnQuery = "SELECT t.id, t.cart_id, t.first_name, t.last_name, t.description, t.txn_date, t.grand_total, c.items, c.paid, c.shipped
        FROM transactions t
        LEFT JOIN cart c ON t.cart_id = c.id
        WHERE c.paid = 1 AND c.shipped = 0
        ORDER BY t.txn_date";
      $txnResults = $db->query($txnQuery);

while($order = mysqli_fetch_assoc($txnResults)){
    $data = "
        <tr>
          <td><a href=\"orders.php?txn_id=". $order['id'] ."\" class=\"btn btn-sm btn-info\">Details<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign\"></span></a></td>
          <td>".$order['first_name'].  " ". $order['last_name'] ."</td>
          <td>".$order['description'] ." </td>
          <td>". money($order['grand_total']) ."</td>
          <td>". pretty_date($order['txn_date']) ."</td>
                </tr>
        ";
}
echo $data;
?>
```

And here is index.php where is the html and ajax code:

```
<?php
  require_once '../core/init.php';
  if(!is_logged_in()){
    header('Location: login.php');
  }
  include 'includes/head.php';
  include 'includes/navigation.php';

?>

<div class="col-lg-12">
  <h4 class="text-center">Orders To Ship       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" style="font-size:23px;"></span></h4>
  <table class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <th></th><th>Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Total</th><th>Date</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table-to-be-inserted">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<script>
function getdata(){
    $.ajax({
                url : "shipping.php",
                success: function(data){
                    $("#table-to-be-inserted").html(data);
                    setTimeout(getdata, 1000);
                }
        });
}
  //Call the function
   getdata();
</script>
```

Now, the problem is that only the last data entered to the database is displayed not all data in the database (I have another name in the database). Also, the data is not showing in the corresponding place in the table. Also, in the console it says [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/, I don't know if this causes the problem or not actually.

[As seen in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjz1e.png)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why only the last data is displayed is that you are replacing the value in `$data` over and over again in the loop. It must be like this:

```php
while($order = mysqli_fetch_assoc($txnResults)){
    $data .= "
        <tr>
          <td><a href=\"orders.php?txn_id=". $order['id'] ."\" class=\"btn btn-sm btn-info\">Details<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign\"></span></a></td>
          <td>".$order['first_name'].  " ". $order['last_name'] ."</td>
          <td>".$order['description'] ." </td>
          <td>". money($order['grand_total']) ."</td>
          <td>". pretty_date($order['txn_date']) ."</td>
        </tr>
        ";
}
```

Use `.=` to concatenate on your `$data` variable.

Secondly, can you specify exactly how it does not appear in the corresponding element? Like, where does it end up?

Comment: Have another statement initalizing `$data` before that `while` statement, like
`$data = "";`
before the `while` statement

Comment: I put `$data = "";` before while statement now the error message is gone but the table is empty there is no values displayed

Comment: Can you `echo` `$data` after the `while` statement?

Comment: You told me to remove before. Anyway, I've added `echo $data;` after while and left `$data = "";` before while. Now, I got back to the first problem, only the last value from the database is shown

Comment: I overlooked that `echo` statement because I was just explaining how the loop works. Now, what does your `echo` display?

Comment: As I told you only the last value from the database

Comment: Have you already tried that query if it really yields more than 1 record (no offense, just making sure)? Or can you show us your table and your data?

Comment: maybe you can send a dbfiddle link of it. sorry that's the only way i see

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there is more than one record in the database

Comment: yes, but maybe the `JOIN` matches only one record among those records.